# Firebase Admin Query : collection where documentId() IN Array of ids

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

This query works with the Web Firebase SDK :

```
firestore.collection("recipes").where(firebase.firestore.FieldValue.documentId(), 'in', ['recipe12','recipe17']).get()
```

But in my cloud functions with 'firebase-admin', I get this error :

> Error: The corresponding value for firebase.firestore.FieldValue.documentId() must be a
>   string or a DocumentReference.

Comment: In the last weeks, several questions on SO where created with the same problem. You may contact Firebase support directly, including all the relevant details:
https://firebase.google.com/support/

Comment: *were created...

Comment: I have this issue also. I filed it here: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/issues/990

Answer (score 3):

It's `firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId()`, both in Web and Admin SDKs.

Web: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldPath.html#documentid

Adimin: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/FieldPath.html#.documentId

`FieldValue.documentId()` should be `undefined`.

Comment: sorry : 
const FieldPath  = firebase.firestore.FieldValue